# How to pass the messages from one page to another using php

Tags: php, session, url, session-variables

I want to pass a predefined messages from a PHP page to another.i having two buttons(i.e are images) if user clicks the button its will redirect to the contact form page when its redirect it will show the predefined message in a message box regarding the button clicked .

also when i open the the contact form page still message is displaying with out clicking the button.

e.g. let's say that I have these message:

```
$message="Teamxxxx"
$message1="1xxxx"
```

and I want to pass them from index.php to contactform.php when the button is clicked

what i tried like this in index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = 'xxxxxx ';
$_SESSION['message1'] = 'xxxxxx ';
$_SESSION['message2'] = 'xxxxxx ';

?>  


<a href="contact_form.php"  class="tbutton large"><i class="arrow_right" ></i><i style="margin:0 0 0 0px" class="icon_comment_alt"></i><span>Get</span></a>

<a href="contact_form.php"  class="tbutton large"><i class="arrow_right" ></i><i style="margin:0 0 0 0px" class="icon_comment_alt"></i><span>Get1</span></a>
```

my contact form.php

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    echo $_SESSION['message']; 
    unset($_SESSION['message']); 
    session_destroy(); 

?>
```

Can any one guide me how to do it thanks

Comment: And what is the problem now?

Comment: it only displaying the first message

Comment: Because you have `$_SESSION['message']`, `$_SESSION['message1'];` [...]. If you want many messages into one varialbe (an array) add each messages in `$_SESSION['message'][]`.

Comment: Why you are unsetting it at the same point of time? Comment the code for unset() and destroy() and check once.

Answer (score 0):

In my contactform.php

First assign those two session variables to temporary variable and then unset the sessions and assign those temp variables where you wanted

```
  session_start();

  $msg1 = $_SESSION['message1']; 
  $msg2 = $_SESSION['message2']; 
  unset($_SESSION['message1']); 
  unset($_SESSION['message2']); 
  session_destroy(); 

?>
```